# CSS3 Gradient - grey instead of white

Tags: google-chrome, css, gradient

i saw the [great example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ReadMoreFade/) of [Chris Coyier here](http://css-tricks.com/8030-text-fade-read-more/) for a *read more* button.
My try was it, to use the this example for a simple fadeout from white to transparent of a text, but i only got a grey gradient.

Exmaple here: http://jsfiddle.net/9adZ3/

So guys please tell me how to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Chris Coyier himself mentions at the end of the article you're linking, the keyword transparent is really rgba(0,0,0,0), so that's transparent black. When you create a gradient from white to transparent black, the result is gray.

You must transition from white to rgba(255,255,255,0), which is transparent white.

http://jsfiddle.net/FnfTA/

Comment: This is something I never thought about, but found it relevant when using a headless version of Chromium to print to PDF. Transparent to white gradients would render greyish on white backgrounds until I replaced `transparent` with `rgba(255,255,255,0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
#fade {
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;

    //for mozilla based
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #ebebeb, #999999);

    //for chrome based
    background: #F6F6F6 -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#999999), to(#ebebeb));  

    // for IE
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#999999',endColorstr='#ebebeb');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9adZ3/2/